# Force CSS flex row wrap in a complex layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

I have this CSS and HTML:

```css
.area {
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 0.15em;
}

.column,
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex: auto;
  gap: 0.25em;
}

.column {
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.row {
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex: 1;
}

button {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: start;
  gap: 0.25em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.row>button {
  align-self: flex-start;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="space">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column area">
        <button>Button 1</button>
        <button>Button 1</button>
        <button>Button 1</button>
      </div>
      <div class="column area">
        <button>Button 2</button>
        <button>Button 2</button>
        <button>Button 2</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column area">
            <button>Button 3</button>
            <button>Button 3</button>
            <button>Button 3</button>
            <button>Button 3</button>
            <button>Button 3</button>
            <button>Button 3</button>
          </div>
          <div class="column area">
            <button>Button 4</button>
            <button>Button 4</button>
            <button>Button 4</button>
            <button>Button 4</button>
          </div>
          <div class="column">
            <div class="row area">
              <button>Button 5</button>
              <button>Button 5</button>
              <button>Button 5</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row area">
              <button>Button 6</button>
              <button>Button 6</button>
              <button>Button 6</button>
              <button>Button 6</button>
              <button>Button 6</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row area">
          <button>Button 7</button>
          <button>Button 7</button>
          <button>Button 7</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column area">
        <button>Button 8</button>
        <button>Button 8</button>
        <button>Button 8</button>
        <div class="row area">
          <button>Button 9</button>
          <button>Button 9</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to make rows with `Button 5`, `Button 6` and `Button 9` wrap instead of making whole column jump bellow? Rows definitely have space left, but buttons wrap only when row takes full viewport width. I'd like them to wrap earlier if there's still space left.

Sadly CSS grid is not an option for specific reasons

I hope that makes sense and would really appreciate some help

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: How do I add snippets you could run as I see on other posts?

Comment: Edit your question and look for the `<>` icon. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Comment: Basically NO. I suggest you look into CSS-Grid.

Comment: Sadly grid is not an option in my case :( Will ad this info to the question too